# Is it possible to send Telegram private messages within PHP?

Tags: php, sms, telegram

We have an application in which new things are sending via SMS. We want to send new contents via telegram to users too. I'v red Telegram API but I couldn't find PHP sample codes there.

We prefer to send messages PRIVATELY not via a bot or something else.

Same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30497635/telegram-based-chat-on-a-php-based-site-howto)

**UPDATE :** We finally decided to use Bot API instead of writing client Application. Because of the complexity behind Telegram API protocol !

Comment: Have you tried something? Please Provide your code.

Comment: No, I'm looking for something to try! A sample code or a tutorial to make  a telegram client application

Comment: It really is not that hard to write, you could start here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35517628/44080